# Is there any way where we can pass the control to the second @Test execution ,instead of going to @BeforeMethod in selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

I am new to automation and trying to automate one website

My page model look like this

```
class A
{
   @BeforeMethod:here I open the url: opens the HOMEPAGE

   @Test:I automate some thing on HOMEPAGE,[Ex:click to go] to MENUPAGE

   @Test:I automate something on MENUPAGE to go thirdlink
}
```

But before it executes the second @Test(MENUPAGE) it calls the @BeforeMethod . So is there any way this can be stopped ,so that I don't want to keep opening the browser on every test case .

Comment: There's a few different versions of the before tag with testNG, including @beforesuite which sounds like what you're after. I've not used it myself, but there should be some good info here.

http://testng.org/doc/selenium.html
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/testng/testng-beforesuite-example/

Comment: Do you want your browser to remain open for all test classes in a suite then move the code from existing beforemethod to beforesuite. For keeping open for all tests in classes defined in the <test>  tag use beforetest. For test methods in each class use beforeclass.

Comment: It's not a good practice to have tests depend on each other. Have Test1 navigate to the home page and do your testing there. Have Test2 navigate to the menu page and do your testing there, and so on.

Comment: @JeffC It depends. In case of functional testing like here, dependent tests is not a so bad practice because tests are more test steps.

Comment: @juherr You'll have to point me to a link of best practices that states that it's OK to have tests depend on each other. I've never seen one.

Comment: @JeffC I didn't say it is a best practice. But dependent test (aka step) is a common pattern used by selenium users.

Comment: @juherr There are a lot of things that are commonly used that I see on SO that aren't good practices. Just because it's common doesn't mean it's a good idea. My statement was that it's not a good practice, which it is not. To say that it's common doesn't mean it's still not a bad practice.

Comment: @JeffC I'd love to see how you implement test steps, like login/logout, in selenium without duplication (which is a bad practice too). My personal feeling is JBehave or Cucumber are the good tools but I'm not here to judge the needs of users ;)

Comment: @juherr I use the page object model. No duplication.

Answer (score 1):

you can use @BeforeTest and @Beforesuite if you just want to just open the webpage once and do a continues test

@BeforeSuite: The annotated method will be run before all tests in this suite have run.
@BeforeTest: The annotated method will be run before any test method belonging to the classes inside the  tag is run.

Comment: `@BeforeClass` is possible too.